# I need to re input if the user doesnt't input 3 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I have this code

```
n,h,y=input("Enter three values: ").split(" ")
```

If user input 1 value or 2 values there is an error (not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
How to re input if user make this error? using while True and if statement?.

Comment: You could solve this using `while` and `if`; why don't you try?

Comment: check the length before unpacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ِYou can use the below code:

```
n, *others = input("Enter three values: ").split(" ")
```

In the above code based on the number of input numbers `others` is a list with zero to infinite numbers in it.
For example, if you write `1 10 2`. `others` is a list with `[10, 2]` value and if you just write one number `1`, `others` is an empty list.

Comment: I got you thanks

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def take3Input():
    Loop = True
    while Loop:
        try:
            n,h,y=input("Enter three values: ").split(" ")
            Loop =False
        except:
            print("please input 3 values")


take3Input()
```